# getting error when trying to compile flutter application on simulator or ios device

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, xcode

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _FlutterMethodNotImplemented

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_FlutterBasicMessageChannel

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_FlutterError

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_FlutterEventChannel

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_FlutterMethodChannel

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_FlutterStandardMessageCodec

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_FlutterStandardMethodCodec

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_FlutterStandardReader

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_FlutterStandardReaderWriter

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_FlutterStandardWriter

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: *OBJC_METACLASS*$_FlutterStandardReader

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: *OBJC_METACLASS*$_FlutterStandardReaderWriter

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: *OBJC_METACLASS*$_FlutterStandardWriter